# SwiftUI Canvas: Implementing with ScrollView and drawing upon loading

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have two questions in regard to using the SwiftUI Canvas.

1. For some reason, when my Canvas is inside of a ScrollView, nothing draws. Why would that be and how can I resolve that issue?
2. I would like to draw lines upon loading the Canvas. I'm not sure how to do so. Even with a declared variable with points, nothing displays until a gesture I have implemented activates.

Below is the code that I have. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import SwiftUI

struct LineData {
    var points: [CGPoint]
    var color: Color
}

struct CanvasExample: View {
    @State var lines: [LineData] = [LineData(points: [CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)], color: .black)]
    @State var selectedColor: Color = Color.black
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView (showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack {
                Canvas { ctx, size in
                    for line in lines {
                        var path = Path()
                        path.addLines(line.points)
                        
                        ctx.stroke(path, with: .color(line.color), style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 5, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                    }
                }.gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .local)
                    .onChanged({ value in
                        let position = value.location
                        
                        if value.translation == .zero {
                            lines.append(LineData(points: [position], color: selectedColor))
                        } else {
                            guard let lastIndex = lines.indices.last else {
                                return
                            }
                            
                            lines[lastIndex].points.append(position)
                        }
                    })
                  )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want a drag gesture on the canvas to draw lines. How would the scroll view scroll then?

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you for your response. That's a good point. I suppose I need to rethink that aspect.